# Count the number of times a project has had it's completion date change

Tags: microsoft-excel

```
Project             Est Comp    Need Date  Revision Date
ABC123BLDP01.001    1/1/2017    2/14/2017   12/31/2017
ABC123BLDP01.001    1/12/2017   2/14/2017   1/5/2017
ABC123BLDP01.001    2/25/2017   2/14/2017   2/14/2017
ABC123BLDP01.001    4/30/2017   2/14/2017   3/31/2017
ABC123BLDP01.001    5/26/2017   2/14/2017   4/27/2017
```

I have a table that looks similar to the above.  It has hundreds of projects in it and I am trying to think of the easiest way to count the number of times each project has had the second column (Est Comp) changed.  The data is in excel.  Do I need VBA or can I make a COUNTIFS statement here?  I can't think of how to make it check for a difference in the dates row by row for the same project with COUNTIFS.

Comment: When you say changed, do you mean like above where it adds a new row or like changed by the user (i.e. me changing the 1/1/2017 up there to 1/2/2017)?

Comment: this data comes from a database that has snapshotted data.  so someone goes into the system that tracks projects and they change the est comp and I just need to figure out how to see the # of times a project has had the est comp date changed.  I export the data to excel to work with.  So I guess just count the # of rows for each project with a different est. comp date.

Comment: Then a COUNTIF should work well here.  It would be `=COUNTIF(range, criteria)` where the _range_ would be the project column (so something like A:A) and the _criteria_ is the project name (so something like $A$2).

Comment: except that the project could be in there without a date change.  I guess I should have expanded my data example to show that.  They may have made another change that didn't change the est comp date, so I need to only count the ones where the Est Comp changed.

Comment: `=COUNTIFS(A:A,$A$2,B:B,"<>")`
I have added an extra criteria in there, the B:B is the Est Comp row (which can be changed if blank), and the `"<>"` says if it is not blank.  You can change around a few values to suit your need here, mainly the rows and the $A$2 to select which job number you would like to count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comment above, it seems you want to count only the rows for a given project where the Est Comp date changed, i.e. the rows with *distinct* dates. This means a given Est Comp date will only be counted once, even if there are multiple occurrences of that Est Comp date for a given project.

A good explanation of how to list and count unique and distinct values can be found [here](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2016/04/21/get-list-unique-values-excel/). And some examples using the SUMIF() function are given [here](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-sumif-function).

The approach shown in the picture below requires a "helper" column as shown.  The formula for the helper column is `=1/COUNTIFS(A$2:A$16,A2,B$2:B$16,B2)`.  This counts the number of times a given combination of Project and Est Comp date occurs in the list, and then takes the reciprocal of that number.

For example, Project ABC... occurs only once with an Est Comp date of 1/1/17, but it occurs twice with an Est Comp date of 1/12/17. So the reciprocals are 1 and 0.5.  The reason for doing this is that summing these numbers for a given project gives the number of distinct combinations of the Project and Est Comp columns, which is how many different Est Comp dates there are per project.

The link above explains this in more detail if you're interested.

[image]

Now let's make a list of the Projects. Cell F2 has this formula:

```
 =IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$16,MATCH(0,INDEX(COUNTIF($F$1:F1,$A$2:$A$16),0,0),0)),"")
```

Note that there MUST be a row above the first row of data for this formula to work correctly. You have column names, so you'll be fine.

Now the only thing left to do is count the number of distinct Est Comp dates for each Project.  The formula in G2 is:

```
 =SUMIF(A$2:A$16,F2,E$2:E$16)
```

This formula sums the Helper column for each Project, and spits out the number of different Est Comp dates for each Project.  The number of times the date *changed* might be 1 less than this number, but you can decide that and subtract 1 if you need to.

I hope this helps and good luck.

Answer (score 0):

A Pivot Table might work. In the example below, I added data and had the pivot table count the "revision date". You'll notice job 123 has 7 entries, but since there is no revision for 3 of them, the pivot only counts 4.
[image]

You could adapt this to only count the column you wish to use. To create a pivot table, select a cell in your table and go to the "Insert" Tab and select "Pivot Table". Choose where you want the table to go, then add your data. You may need to change the format of the "value" field from SUM to COUNT.

Comment: Wow, why didn't I even think of that.  Perfect.

Comment: I don't think this will do what you want.  If there's a row containing Project 123 and an Est Comp date equal to another Est Comp date, it will be counted twice.  I think you said you want to count only unique combinations of Project and Est Comp date.